# Как в MySQL правильно искать фразу целиком

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с текстовым полем, содержащим ссылки. В разных строках таблицы эти ссылки произвольной длины. В таблице 14 млн строк. Мне нужно брать ссылку из произвольной строки и очень быстро находить ее дубли в других строках. Т.е. тут идет поиск по полю целиком, а не частичное совпадение.

Что я пробовал делать:

1. сделал это поле типом text и искал вот так: where `url`='$url' - запрос обрабатывается около 10 секунд.
2. сделал это поле типом varshar(1000) и сделал по нему индекс, и искал вот так: where `url`='$url' - запрос обрабатывается около 10 секунд, т.е. не дало никакого прироста.
3. делать для этого поля fulltext-индекс не вижу смысла, т.к. я не ищу в нем частичные совпадения
4. делать для этого поля поиск через where `url` like '%$url%' не вижу смысла, т.к. я не ищу в нем частичные совпадения
5. делать для этого поля поиск через where `url` like '$url' не вижу смысла, т.к. это еще медленнее, чем 
   `url`='$url'

Посоветуйте, как правильно, и главное - быстро, искать в таком случае?

Comment: sphinx в помощь

Comment: Покажите DDL для варианта 2 и explain для запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Добавь ещё одно поле и сгенери в него хэш от ссылок. Любой короткий быстрый хэш. Например, CRC32. Уже это поле проиндексируй (можно целиком, а можно первые 2-3 байта - хватит вполне). И по этому полю ищи совпадения. А только потом проверяй сам урл.

Поиск по короткому (НЕ уникальному!) хэшу даст огромный прирост скорости. Но всё равно придётся после этого сравнить и сами урлы. Поэтому индекс лучше сделать составным.

```
..,
crc32 char, // byte, clob, blob.. raw
url varchar,
index idx crc32(4), url(8),
..,
```

А искать потом например так:

```
where crc32 = :crc32
    and url = :url
```

Должно просто летать!